# iOS and persistent network connection ( websocket, push notification )

Tags: ios, websocket, push-notification

My application needs fast and reliable way of communication from the server to a mobile app.
As fast as I understand, APNS isn't 100% reliable ( they offer best effort delivery ),
persistent network connection via websockets is a good option, but if an application goes to background, all connections are closed. ( unless they are marked as audio/location/voip connections, and they are not, my app doesn't relate to these services ).

Can anyone suggest some work arounds??

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: There is a 'background fetch' mode available for apps in iOS, where your app will periodically be launched in order to make a connection and check for data.  This is not exactly what you have described, because the app makes a new connection to the server each time, it is not a persistent connection.

Comment: Tnx, for a suggestion, but it doesn't fit my needs.
I need pretty fast way of communication and making a connection 5 times in a second will eat a battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APN is your best bet, for a number of reasons. They are sufficiently reliable (it is unlikely that you'll get a more reliable solution in your app). APN also works even if your app is in background, suspended, or not running at all – something that simply cannot be done at app level.

Besides, Apple explicitly forbids any other form of push notifications in the AppStore (i.e. apps with push notifications implemented not via APNS will be rejected).

Comment: Tnx for confirmation.
By the way, if have VOIP app, would I be able to have two open connections??? one for voice and another just for some meta data trasfering? ( Given that both sockets will be marked as voip )